# Elasticsearch index document to existing index 504 timeout

Tags: elasticsearch

When I try to index a document that I made an index for using

```
curl -vvv -XPUT 'https://es/existing_index/existing_or_nonexsitgin_mapping/1?timeout=999h ...document
```

I get a 504 (despite the timeout I set. The index is currently empty). But when I try to index the document into a nonexisting index it returns successfully immediately:

```
curl -vvv -XPUT 'https://es/NONEXISTING_index/existing_or_nonexsitgin_mapping/1?timeout=999h ...document
```

But the index is created incorrectly because I didn't create it.

I use elastic search version 2.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - the index had a property for amount of shards and replicas which exceeded the actual amount of available shards on the host. Too bad there was no error when creating the index.